# Vim PowerlineSymbols displayed incorrectly

Tags: macos, vim, fonts, glyph, vim-powerline

I am having problems trying to get the PowerlineSymbols/Glyphs to displayed correctly on the powerline.

I have already tried all the available fonts suggested by [Lokaltog](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts). I have also tried to set the font to be used in my ~/.vimrc file in different ways, however for some reason the powerline keeps on displaying the wrong characters. I also changed the fonts in iTerm.

I have already tried the fontforge and this solutions:

- [vim-powerline plugin problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066570/vim-powerline-plugin-problems)
- [Font Patching for OS X](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fontpatching.html#os-x)

This is how my `~/.vimrc` looks right for the powerline:

```
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-powerline'
let g:Powerline_symbols = "fancy"

"IndentationGuide <Leader>ig
Bundle 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides.git'
let g:indent_guides_auto_colors = 0
autocmd VimEnter,Colorscheme * :hi IndentGuidesOdd  guibg=#998f84 ctermbg=245
autocmd VimEnter,Colorscheme * :hi IndentGuidesEven guibg=#d9cec3 ctermbg=252
```

This is a screenshot of what I am currently getting:
[image]

Not sure exactly what I am missing, I will a appreciate a push in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [vim-powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline is deprecated, try [the new version](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline) and, if you still have problems, use [its issue tracker](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline/issues). Or try an alternative like [vim-airline](https://github.com/bling/vim-airline). Or take a moment and ask yourself: do you *really* need such a thing and all the hassle that goes with it?

Comment: @romainl Thanks for replying. Not really sure what keeps on causing the problem. However, I installed back vim-airline (using powerline symbols) and it work like a charm. Thanks for the suggestions and helping out.

Comment: But where exactly is your `set guifont=...` line? You shouldn't leave that out.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, until I realized that I hadn't set the "Non-ASCII Font" in my iTerm preferences.  iTerm uses that font to render Unicode glyphs (like those employed by Powerline).